# Browserify not exposing index object

Tags: javascript, node.js, release, browserify

I have a node module that I am trying to distribute via browserify. The project has many functions, and these functions are typically tied to a root object sort of like jQuery's $, underscore's _ or Leaflet's L. My index.js looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  f1: require('./lib/f1'),
  f2: require('./lib/f2')
}
```

This works fine in node.js since I can do:

```
var x = require('x')
x.f1()
x.f2()
```

The problem is that when I use browserify, it eliminates my root object and flattens everything out. In the browser, this happens

```
<script src='x.js'>
...
f1() // works fine
f2() // works fine
x.f1() // x undefined
x.f2() // x undefined
```

This is how I am using browserify (basically the default):

```
browserify index.js > x.js
```

Does anyone know a way to get browserify to not flatten everything out, and simply expose the root object?

Comment: `browserify -h | grep -- --standalone`

Comment: That did it. I just added '-s global_name'. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it for future reference.